# Can't use or install Microsoft Windows after changing disk to GPT partition style to use Linux

Tags: linux, windows, uefi, mbr, gpt

I am having some trouble installing Windows or using it, originally I had an MBR partition table which only allowed three partitions and I wanted to install Linux and I couldn't so I changed MBR to GPT but then Windows boot partition disappeared.

If I tried using Windows installation USB it gives the error the disk is of GPT Partition style and that was on CSM boot so I changed to UEFI boot and it doesn't work at all, not even linux boot discs or windows ones work on UEFI ever since I changed disk partition.

For information:

I am using A Toshiba Satellite laptop c50d-a-11q and my bios has two boot options: `csm` and `uefi`. No legacy but I checked that csm acts as legacy anyway. I am running Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS right now.

I had this problem in the past and followed diskpart and it wiped months of stuff all my linux and windows gone and I lost my original windows operating system as well. That was when I changed GPT to MBR. I hope there is a solution to this, I value any support.

Comment: This is, at best, difficult to get back to where you were. Your problem is that in BIOS mode Windows cannot boot from GPT disk (but Linux can) and when you set it over to UEFI mode Windows was still set up to boot from an MBR disk and lacked all the setup necessary for GPT disks or UEFI firmware. I believe Acronis may be able to convert a GPT disk to MBR but it is not guaranteed to work. You should not randomly change between GPT and MBR and CSM or UEFI modes unless you know what you are doing, they all require specific operating system support and you can lose data as you have already found.

Comment: If you have any valuable data on that disk then the best thing you can do is take it out of the computer, buy a new disk and then install a fresh operating system on that and then recover the data from the old disk using a USB cradle. Anything you do from here could just make things worse.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, so There is nothing I can really do about this, Windows and Linux can never be installed and able to boot on my computer .

Comment: I appreciate the support. I guess there is nothing I can do but to purchase a new disk. thanks for your help